# Failure to reproduce covariance matrix

Tags: r, matrix, covariance

I am trying to reproduce covariance matrix for the generated data

```
 set.seed(1)
 datam <- round((matrix((rnorm(300, mean = 2, sd = 0.5)), nrow = 100, ncol = 
 3)), digits = 2)
```

to do that, I should multiply this matrix's transpose by the original matrix and multiply further by 1/n, where n=100 and transpose is the following

```
datamT <- t(datam)
```

so,

```
datamT%*%datam*1/100
```

FAILS to reproduce the covariance matrix of datam, originally determined by

```
cov(datam)
```

I am not sure where the mistake is, so help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subtract the column means for the approximation to be valid.

```
x <- datam-rep(colMeans(datam),each=nrow(datam))
## or use scale(datam, scale=FALSE)

t(x)%*%x/(nrow(x)-1)
              [,1]          [,2]         [,3]
[1,]  0.2015461010 -0.0001247677  0.004172283
[2,] -0.0001247677  0.2289751111 -0.012216242
[3,]  0.0041722828 -0.0122162424  0.266885848

t(x)%*%x/(nrow(x)-1)-cov(datam)
              [,1]          [,2]         [,3]
[1,] -1.387779e-16  7.047314e-19 0.000000e+00
[2,]  7.047314e-19 -5.551115e-17 0.000000e+00
[3,]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16
```

Comment: It's `t(x)%*%x/(nrow(x)-1)` to get the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to have a look at the formula of the **covariance** in [here.](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/finance/covariance/)
It is the average of the summation of the each row's deviation from their means. If it is a sample covariance, then you use `n-1` instead of `n`.To replicate it,

```
var_cov_matrix <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:ncol(datam)){ 
    for(j in 1:ncol(datam)) {

        var_cov_matrix[i,j] <-sum((datam[,i]- mean(datam[,i])) * (datam[,j]- mean(datam[,j])))/(nrow(datam)-1)



    }

}

             V1            V2           V3
1  0.2015461010 -0.0001247677  0.004172283
2 -0.0001247677  0.2289751111 -0.012216242
3  0.0041722828 -0.0122162424  0.266885848
```

which is same with `cov(datam)` as,

```
              [,1]          [,2]         [,3]
[1,]  0.2015461010 -0.0001247677  0.004172283
[2,] -0.0001247677  0.2289751111 -0.012216242
[3,]  0.0041722828 -0.0122162424  0.266885848
```